# What's Firefox's default browser helper plugin?

Tags: macos, firefox, plugins

On a freshly installed Firefox there is a plugin named:

> Default Browser Helper 537

It seems to be something from Apple but i couldn't find more information about it.

What is it and why it there?
Do we need it?

---

OS X 10.9 (and 10.9.1)
Firefox 25.0.1 (and 26)

Comment: Firefox (26.0) identifies the same problem on my MacPro running OSX 10.9 at their "Add-Ons Manager". The results of "Research" got me here - still no answer what it is and how to fix it!

Comment: Yes, for Firefox 26 the same thing. I don't think it is a necessarily "problem" that needs to be fixed, but I would definitely like to know more details on the subject...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did some digging and [documented my findings](https://www.ctrl.blog/entry/default-browser-plugin.html).

The plug-in is used to produce the below dialog. It can be triggered by Apple from inside any other web browser. It is unclear when and where this is used.

[image: Would you like to go on Safari?]

Comment: Interesting! What do you mean can be triggered from inside any other web browser?

Comment: The plug-in is loaded as a plug-in in every web browser. Which means the dialog can be opened from within any browser. See the link for specifics.

Comment: I have check the link, but I am still a little bit confused. Maybe it is just the wording. The dialog can be opened from let's say Safari browser? How safari has anything to do with the plugins that are installed in Firefox?

Comment: Lyk: the plug-in is installed in a standard location for plug-ins. All browsers look in this location and load all plug-ins they find there. So this plug-in from Apple is included in every browser. The plug-in can open a dialog and ask you to change your default to Safari.

Comment: Oh, really? I thought that plugins were specific to each browser and that each browser keeps them in its own directory (at least with firefox in other unix-like systems that is the case)

Comment: Have a look in /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/